# Arduino shield sim7600 (AT command not working)

Tags: arduino-uno, sim7600

SIM7600 shield worked before with Arduino UNO. I was able to send AT command and receive OK.
After sending "AT+IPREX=19200", it stopped working. I cannot receive OK by entering AT in Serial Monitor. My serial monitor has always been at 115200 baud rate.

I tried to restart Arduino and Shield and compile the original code again but it doesn't work. I still do not get response by entering AT.

Comment: All SIMCOM modules are auto-baud rate, you don't need to explicitly change baud rate with AT Command. All you need is to set your Serial Monitor to the desire baud rate and send a couple of "AT" to auto-sync.